# C program is behaving giving weird values in Windows but works fine in Ubuntu

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote a program for a small task in school on my laptop with Ubuntu on. I wasnt having any problems when writing the program. It worked perfectly fine and did everything it should. But when I moved it over to my Windows PC it gave me some very weird values and I cant seem to figure out whats wrong with it. I use the same IDE, CodeBlocks 16.01, on both Ubuntu and Windows. Ive been trying to solve this for several hours but im stuck so I would really appreciate some help.

If I for example enter the value 50 on every prompt I will get the results of 200 in both printf-methods after the while-loop, like it should be since 50+50+50+50 equals 200. In windows however I get 240 in total_weight and 100 in total_height which to me doesnt make any sense. Whats the cause of this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int weights[3], heights[3], i = 0;
int total_weight, total_height;

while (i <= 3)
{
    printf("Person %d, enter your weight (kg): ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&weights[i]);
    printf("Person %d, enter your height (cm): ",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &heights[i]);

    //Calculations for total weight and total length of all the people
    total_weight = total_weight + weights[i];
    total_height = total_height + heights[i];

    printf("\n\tPerson %d's weight and height: %dkg, %dcm\n\n", i+1, weights[i], heights[i]);
    i++;
}

//Printing the results of the earlier calculations
printf("\tTotal weight of everyone: %d\n", total_weight);
printf("\tTotal height of everyone: %d\n", total_height);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `int total_weight, total_height;` - what do you think the values of total_weight and total_height are after this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, by saying

```
 while (i <= 3)
```

you're going [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), for out-of-bound memory access.

To elaborate, C arrays have 0-based indexing. So for an array with a dimension of 3, will have valid indexes from 0 to 2, inclusive.

So, you should use

```
while (i < 3)
```

to stay in the bounds.

That said, in your code, `total_weight` and `total_height` are automatic local variables and they are used uninitialized. Hence, they contain indeterminstic values and using them causes UB, again. You have to explicitly initialize them to, say, 0.

Comment: At first I used while (i < 4) which didnt work either. It gives the same incorrect values.

Comment: @mmollle: In the expression `weights[3]`, `3` designates the number of elements, not the final index. 3 elements means that indices go from 0 through 2.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the elaboration. I thought I was clear on that point, nevertheless. :)

Comment: Alright, by setting total_weight and total_height to 0 in the declaring statements I now get the correct values. But how come they work without being initialized when I run them in Ubuntu?

Comment: @mmollle and those were not the only problems. Regarding the __Undefined behavior__, that's the _beauty_ of it. Do read the linked article to understand it more.

Comment: Hmmm.. what warrants a downvote here? Please enlight me.

Answer (score 3):

you are overflowing your arrays.  you are entering 4 values in each buy only allocating 3 spaces.

Comment: I tried allocateing more spaces in the arrays, the values I recieve is now still 240 from the total_weight and 6899064 in the total_height int. And the arrays with 3 allocated spaces still works on my Ubuntu, how is that possible?

Comment: the reason it sometimes works is that some compilers, especially when they are *not* optimizing, will pad local variables with extra space for debugging or other information.  however, as others have pointed out, none of this is actually relevant to the problem you're having, which was the uninitialized total_weight and total_height variables.

Answer (score 3):

You are using uninitialized `total_height`, `total_weight`:

```
int total_weight, total_height; 

/* ... */
total_weight = total_weight + weights[i];
total_height = total_height + heights[i];
```

They should be initialized with zeros:

```
int total_weight = 0, total_height = 0;
```

Also when `i == 3` you are trying to access memory out of `weights` / `heights` arrays. You can solve it in two ways:

1. disallow acces to 4th element via condition correction: `while(i < 3) {`
2. declare more capable arrays `int weights[4], heights[4];`

Answer (score 2):

Compiling your code on Linux (Debian based, like Ubuntu) with

```
gcc-4.9 -O3 -g3  -W -Wall -Wextra  -std=c11 stackover.c -o stackover
```

results in the following warnings:

```
stackover.c: In function ‘main’:
stackover.c:12:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     scanf("%d",&weights[i]);
     ^
stackover.c:14:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     scanf("%d", &heights[i]);
     ^
stackover.c:17:42: warning: iteration 3u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
     total_weight = total_weight + weights[i];
                                          ^
stackover.c:9:7: note: containing loop
 while (i <= 3)
       ^
stackover.c:18:18: warning: ‘total_height’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     total_height = total_height + heights[i];
                  ^
stackover.c:17:18: warning: ‘total_weight’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     total_weight = total_weight + weights[i];
```

With those in mind, we can change the code to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int weights[4], heights[4], i = 0;
  int total_weight = 0, total_height = 0;
  int res;
  // four persons
  while (i <= 3) {
    printf("Person %d, enter your weight (kg): ", i + 1);
    res = scanf("%d", &weights[i]);
    if(res != 1){
      fprintf(stderr,"Only one person, thank you\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Person %d, enter your height (cm): ", i + 1);
    res = scanf("%d", &heights[i]);
    if(res != 1){
      fprintf(stderr,"Only one person, thank you\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //Calculations for total weight and total length of all the people
    total_weight = total_weight + weights[i];
    total_height = total_height + heights[i];

    printf("\n\tPerson %d's weight and height: %dkg, %dcm\n\n", i + 1,
           weights[i], heights[i]);
    i++;
  }

  //Printing the results of the earlier calculations
  printf("\tTotal weight of everyone: %d\n", total_weight);
  printf("\tTotal height of everyone: %d\n", total_height);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);   
}
```